# LinkedStack and displaying the entire stack

Tags: java

I'm having difficulty on these problem. I have 4 problem on it to make it work. I got two of them right for this but the other two is wrong. It is a `toString()` for java:

```
    LLNode<T> node = top;
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    String es = "Empty Stack";

    if (node == null)
    {
        return es;
    }
    s.append("bottom|");
    while (node != null)
    {
        s.append(node.getInfo());
        s.append("|");
        node = node.getLink();

    }
    s.append("top");
    return s.toString();
}
```

It returns:

`bottom|3|4|5|top` instead of `bottom|5|4|3|top`

and my other error is that it returns:

`bottom|5|4|3|2|1|top` instead of `bottom|1|2|3|4|5|top`

If someone have a clue how to do this, that would be great. I'm stuck on it and I don't know why it not returning what I wanted.

This is what it wants

```
@Test  
public void test_toString_on_a_stack_with_multiple_elements() {

    stk1.push(5); stk1.push(4); stk1.push(3);

    Assert.assertEquals("bottom|5|4|3|top", stk1.toString());
}   

@Test  
public void test_toString_on_a_full_stack() {

    stk1.push(1); stk1.push(2); stk1.push(3); stk1.push(4); stk1.push(5);

    Assert.assertEquals("bottom|1|2|3|4|5|top", stk1.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On grounds of your posting, the order in which the elements are printed is wrong. So one solution is to prepend to the StringBuilder instead of appending. As index 0 makes life easier I also moved the "bootom|" after collecting all nodes and prepended it before all the node output in the buffer :

```
LLNode<T> node = top;
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    String es = "Empty Stack";

    if (node == null)
    {
        return es;
    }
    while (node != null)
    {
        s.insert(0, "|");
        s.insert(0, node.getInfo());
        node = node.getLink();

    }
    s.insert(0,"bottom|");
    s.append("top");
    return s.toString();
}
```

(This is untested, written from top  of my head as I do not have your LLNode or anything - so best effort)

Comment: see Answer of @Roland Illig :it may be more performant. Also there may be even more performant solutions to get the items in reversed order( maybe already available in your stack/list implementation if you can go from the end to the beginning). I Stuck to your aproach: it migh be not the most performant, most sophisticated solution but its yours.

Answer (score 1):

Using `StringBuilder.insert` as in kai’s answer makes the code correct but slow for large stacks. A similar approach is to first store the elements in a list, then reverse the list and finally generate the whole string out of the list.

This is the code:

```
public String toString() {
    if (top == null) {
        return "Empty Stack";
    }

    List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    elements.add("top");
    for (LLNode<T> node = top; node != null; node = node.getLink()) {
        elements.add(String.valueOf(node.getInfo()));
    }
    elements.add("bottom");

    elements.reverse();
    return String.join("|", elements);
}
```

I did not test the above code, but I'm confident it works. Just good that you already have the tests available.

In an educational setting, the above code might be unacceptable. This is because a List is conceptually more complicated than a Stack. Therefore the List might not be covered yet in class. Usually, the topics are covered by increasing complexity, therefore a List might use a Stack, but not the other way round. In practical programming, the above code would be ok though.

Comment: Thank you, I give it a try.

Comment: @Roland Illig You are right. I thought if the op wanted to use a container he would use it in the first place. Whats the point of creating a container only to move everything to a different(sure better suited) container and perform operation on that other container. But I do like your answer!